# How to stop a Phaser game and remove it from a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, phaser-framework

I have a single webpage that I want to be able to run three JavaScript games, sequentially. I start one with

```
//jQuery to start a game
$(document).ready(() => {
  //When the logo image is clicked
  $("#logo").click(() => {
    //Get the archery game
    $.getScript('archery.js', () => {
      //Start it
      startArchGame();
      //Remove the image from the HTML doc
      $("#logo").remove();
    });
  })
})
```

Then, inside `archery.js`, once a condition is met, the following code is executed

```
$.getScript('skateboarding.js', () => {
  startSkateGame();
});
game.destroy();
```

The `game.destroy();` stops the game from running in Phaser 3, but the next game is just loaded below the first one, so you can't see it. How can I fix this? Is it possible to delete the first script I got entirely?

Comment: is there an example that you demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph would a GitHub repo work for you?

Comment: yes, share the link please

Comment: @NidhinJoseph https://github.com/roberto257/Olympic-Games

Comment: @RobertSmith have you found an answer to this issue?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal no :/ haven’t looked into it during these holidays though. Someone suggested making each game a scene in phaser but I’d rather not do that

Comment: @ManuelAbascal I have an idea but I don't know how to execute it. I tried adding the game to to the page as a script or within a div, but that didn't work. How could I have the first page as a landing page, and redirect to a new page with the new game when the previous game is finished?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue within the Phaser framework.

I changed `game.destroy()` to `game.destroy(true, false)`.
The first argument of the destroy method, `true`, says that I want to remove the game from the canvas element of the page when I destroy the game. The second argument, `false`, says to NOT remove all of Phaser and its plugins for the page. I set this to false because I want to create another game in Phaser on the page after I destroy my first one.